# UITableViewWith Paging Prev,next button

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I have one `NSMutableArray` that has number of records (suppose 52).

```
for (int i=0;i<=52;i++) {
    [arrSavedCalculation addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bianca lb,Red %d",i]];
}
```

I want to give a paging Prev and Next button at bottom of tableview. and each page display 6 record.How can i do this. i also see this document but not success 
http://www.ke-cai.net/2011/04/pagination-with-uitableview-in-ios.html

Comment: You need to keep an array which is a subset of main array. Keep an instance variable to keep the page, form sub array using `subarrayWithRange:` and then reload the tableView

Comment: thanks for your answer, can you give me example...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with these. Tested and found working. Can be improved.

```
@interface ViewController (){
    //pageNumber will hold the current page index
    NSInteger _pageNumber;
    //keeping the max page number for ease of calculation
    NSUInteger _maxPageNumber;
    //the batch size
    NSUInteger _numberOfVisibleRows;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //Main data array is formed
    NSUInteger rows = 0;
    NSMutableArray *tempArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    while (rows<52) {

        [tempArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Item %d",rows+1]];
        rows++;
    }

    self.mainArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:tempArray];

    _pageNumber = 0;
    _numberOfVisibleRows = 5;
    _maxPageNumber = [self.mainArray count]/_numberOfVisibleRows;

    self.subArray = [self subArrayForPageNumber:_pageNumber];

}

- (NSArray *)subArrayForPageNumber:(NSUInteger)pageNumber{

    NSRange range = NSMakeRange(_pageNumber*_numberOfVisibleRows, _numberOfVisibleRows);
    if (range.location+range.length>[self.mainArray count]) {
        range.length = [self.mainArray count]-range.location;
    }
   return [self.mainArray subarrayWithRange:range];
}

- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(UIBarButtonItem *)button{
    //Same method is used for calculating the page numbers
    if (button.tag ==1) {
        _pageNumber= MIN(_maxPageNumber, _pageNumber+1);
    }else{
        _pageNumber = MAX(0, _pageNumber-1);
    }

    self.subArray = [self subArrayForPageNumber:_pageNumber];
    [self.tableView reloadData];

}
```

[Source Code](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/35012982/Demo%20Projects/DemoPagination.zip)

Comment: hi, this is working fine but now problem with delete and I have one check box in cell. if i select one check box and go next and previous the check box always checked. for other data. how can solve this?

Comment: @SAMIRRATHOD You need to include the selection in your dataSource. For example for each item of your array included a flag also with the displayed title. Change the value of flag on selection. While displaying the checkbox use the value stored in dataSource to set it selected/unselected. Let me know if you have any concerns.

Comment: we saved tempArry subarrayWithRange from main array. how can i change it (checked/Unchecked) in main array. right now it just change in current tempArray, and for current page only.

Comment: @SAMIRRATHOD I hope your title is unique, or introduce a uniqueID or something to your dataSource. When you update the selection. First change the data in the mainArray. Then reload the current page,forming new subArray.

Comment: @Anupdas: Hi, I need the source code for pagination with NEXT and PREV button in TablevIew.  The link you added for source code is not available now. Can, you please share the source code for the same.

Comment: @Anupdas : Hi Anup, please help me out I need the source code for UITableViewWith Paging with Previous and next button. Thanks  in advance.

Answer (score 1):

you should take two array.
1) Your MAIN ARRAY containing all of objects.
2) A Temporary array contain only 6 objects.

While loading tableview use that Temporary Array.

keep a page counter which will count your current page.

According to your 52 objects you can have 52/6 = 9 page but last page contain only 4 object.

like.

```
#define kNumberOfObjectInOnePage 6 
set self.page=0 in "viewDidLoad" //self.page is the page counter.
-(void)nextPage:(id)sender{
    self.page++;
    take 6 objects from main array into temp array
    reload your table view.
}

-(void)previous:(id)sender{
    self.page--;
    take 6 previous object into temp array
    reload your table view.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, yes i did it. but problem is heare "take 6 objects from main array into temp array" first time i take 0 to 5,then 6 to 11,.. then how to know start number and end number?

Comment: This will handle by the page counter. Suppose you are on the 1st Page so self.page = 0 and you have 0-5 object. Next 2nd page self.page = 1 and you are on 6-11 and so on. So the equation is if(self.page == 0){startNum = 0, endNum = kNumberOfObjectInOnePage -1}else{startNum = self.page * kNumberOfObjectInOnePage - kNumberOfObjectInOnePage -1, and end Num = self.page * kNumberOfObjectInOnePage -1 }

Answer (score 0):

> A simple solution is if you are accessing records from web service then ask to him provide the total number of records in initial hits as well as first 6 records to display. If you want to do paging you should keep page 0 or 1 at initial hit to service and as you got 6 records on first page and you find that total records which are given from service is more than the 6 then you have to show `previous` and `next button` otherwise no need of these button.
>
> As you accessing the records you have to put into in an `NSArray` or in `Coredata`. When you press `next button`you have to increase the page count and fetch next 6 records and save to DB or array and reload the table.
>
> if you press `previous button` you have to remove last 6 object from array or you can delete or check some kind last 6 records to display and reload table.

Hope this helps.